# Multiple dynamic routes on the same level in Nuxt possible?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-i18n

Is it possible to have multiple dynamic routes on the same level in NuxtJS?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
pages
--_article.vue
--_city.vue
```

I'm using Nuxt Content and wanted to load different content dynamically with unique layout/design on the same page level.

Comment: Do you mean child routes ? Like you have a page and in that page you have different routes. For example you have account page /account like this and you have different pages in it. /account/main, /account/changepassword. like this ?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to serve different content on the top level like this: /article1, /article2, /city1, /city2, etc. But have different layout/design for each of those two types of content. Not sure if it's even possible with Nuxt

Comment: I appreciate if you accept my answer if it worked for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create two different routes for city and article and under them you can dynamically generate routes. For example, your pages folder should look like this:

```
---| article
-----| _slug.vue
---| city
-----| _slug.vue
```

With this you can achieve routes like:
/city/:city_id 
/article/:article_id

Answer (score 0):

In nuxt3, If you need a catch-all route,you create it by using a file named like [...slug].vue. This will match all routes under that path.
see: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#catch-all-route